# How to handle Firebase Notification i.e. Notification Messages and Data Messages in Android

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the best way to handle both Notification Messages and Data Messages in firebase using Xamarin Android, while the user is in Foreground and Background?

Also, how do I get the notification data, for example, the text of a particular notification?

PS: I have visited the following threads and none actually helped :

[When device screen off then how to handle firebase notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540568/when-device-screen-off-then-how-to-handle-firebase-notification)

[Firebase Notification and Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888917/firebase-notification-and-data)

[Display firebase notification data-message on Android tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074650/display-firebase-notification-data-message-on-android-tray)

Comment: You need detect your application is in Foreground and Background ?

Comment: No, currently all I want to know is how to get the system tray data or call onMessageReceived when in the background.

Comment: You could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193700/retrieve-notification-values-from-a-notification-in-system-tray-android-firebase

Comment: tried it didn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found the answers to my own question so I'm posting the answer for someone who is looking for firebase integration in xamarin.

- Install `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` package to your project.
- Add the following code to your manifest.xml to receive firebase notifications.

  ```
  <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
  <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```
- Now to get the registration token from firebase add a class file and add the following code to it:

  ```
  [Service]
  [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
  public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
  {
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
     {
          const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
          var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
          Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
          SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
      }
     void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
      {
         // Add custom implementation, as needed.
      }
  }
  ```

  Here `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` gets the instance token for the current device, Also the method `SendRegistrationToServer`can be used to send the token to send the token to a server.
- Now add another class to handle notifications on foreground

  ```
  [Service]
  [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
  public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
  {
     // private string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
     {
         base.OnMessageReceived(message);
         string messageFrom = message.From;
         string getMessageBody = message.GetNotification().Body;
         SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body);
     }
  void SendNotification(string messageBody)
  {
      try
      {
          var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
          intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
          var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

          NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
              .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
              .SetContentTitle("Title")
              .SetContentText(messageBody)
              .SetAutoCancel(true)
              .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

          NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
          notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }
     }
   }
  ```

Here the method `SendNotification` is used to explicitly send a notification to the system tray, Since push notifications while the device is in the foreground are not automatically displayed in the system tray.

- When the device is in the background or killed notification is automatically generated and by default the main launcher activity is loaded, to get the data from the background notification you need to use intent as follows(On your main launcher activity):

  ```
    if (Intent.Extras != null)
      {
          foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
          {
              var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
              Log.Debug(TAG, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
          }
      }
  ```
- Also if google play services are not up to date this code might crash your application so to check if google play services are available or not do this :

  ```
  public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
  {
      int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
      if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
      {
          if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
              msgText.Text = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode);
          else
          {
              msgText.Text = "This device is not supported";
              Finish();
          }
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          msgText.Text = "Google Play Services is available.";
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```

Check the below link for information on how to add your project to the firebase console:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm/\

### Update

- After the recent changes in the Android Oreo it is mandatory that you add your Notifications into a Channel for that you need to Create a Notification channel in your MainActivity something like below:

  ```
  void CreateNotificationChannel()
  {
     if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
     {
      // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
      // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
      // channel on older versions of Android.
      return;
     }

    var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
                {
                    Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
                };

  var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
  notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
  }
  ```

Call this method in you MainActivity's OnCreate method.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer! FirebaseInstanceIdService is obsolete so please modify your answer it will benefit to many people. Could you please let us know how to pass the data received in notification to shared project in Xamarin Forms application.

Comment: I haven't got a chance to check the new Firebase push notification changes.

Comment: @BrijeshKumarTripathi Can you check this out : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w2q2D6mR7g&list=PLfbOp004UaYUgjhTHjtSixo-iMdz6PhIv&index=2&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

Comment: Thanks for your great support...!!! Video is really good.

Comment: Happy to help @BrijeshKumarTripathi