# How to integrate firebase in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have read articles about integration of firebase with android that tells to add google services.json file and add some code to gradle.

I cannot find any location in xamarin android.

Has anyone implemented this?

Comment: for what would you use the firebase exactly?

Comment: If it is for notification, here it is. [Link](http://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin)

Comment: It is used for analytics like crash reporting, performance monitoring and many more https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: right, cool, but what exactly are you having trouble implementing?

Comment: its says that to include json file in your project and add some lines of code to gradle, but I don't have gradle (unaware of adding) in my project because I was using Xamarin.Android

Comment: Check my answer out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826887/how-to-handle-firebase-notification-i-e-notification-messages-and-data-messages

Comment: @Amit, hi, have you integrated the firebase?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin#add-the-google-services-json-file).

> 1.Copy google-services.json to the project folder.
>
> 2.Add google-services.json to the app project (click Show All Files in the Solution Explorer, right click google-services.json, then select Include in Project).
>
> 3.Select google-services.json in the Solution Explorer window.
>
> 4.In the Properties pane, set the Build Action to GoogleServicesJson (if the GoogleServicesJson build action is not shown, save and close the Solution, then reopen it):

Comment: Hi,@Amit, like `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'`, it will import this library. Android Studio use [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to build the project, VS use [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx).