# GCM push notification issue in android P (28)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

we're using GCM for push notification for our app with target release to 26.
Using `class GCMJobIntentService extends JobIntentService` for push notification services because of target release 26.

It's now android P released and push notification stopped working. When debugged found below exceptions

> ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf
>   (has extras) } U=0: not found

Due to exception above, it's returning blank gcm token and nothing working for push. Is there someone facing same issue, and if there is any solution to go with GCM without updating to FCM for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this post: [GCM unable to start service intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200431/gcm-unable-to-start-service-intent). You need to upgrade to GCM 11 or higher.

> You are likely be using an older version of GCM.
>
> You may upgrade to GCM 11 or higher, or even better, migrate to FCM. (GCM is now deprecated)
>
> (The latest GCM version is 15.0.1: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1)

Since GCM is going to be taken out soon, it is recommended for you to use FCM instead.