# I receive push notifications on ios but not on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need help with notifications on a project of xamarin.forms on the android platform.

The OnTokenRefresh method works well. I create the token correctly and send it to my server, but the problem is that it never enters the OnMessageReceived method when I send a push. In IOS everything is working correctly.

My manifest > receiver =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.sademo.SademoEvent" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:label="SademoEvent.Android">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDxmjIsYXJ1OMWpqqheenbBoK5GKLWzAvg" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
      android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                 android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

My FirebaseInstanceIdService implementation =>

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        Helper.Settings.PlatformSNS = refreshedToken;
    }
}
```

My FirebaseMessagingService implementation =>

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "-------------------------------ES UN MENSAJE-------------------------------");
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
        
    }
}
```

---

## Solved

The problem was (or I think it is) in the package name.
old => com.mycompany.Company.
New => com.mycompany.company.

With the new package everything works fine.

Comment: So, what is it? The title says Android works. In the question it says Android doesn't work.

Comment: It was a mistake, and it was fixed. Thanks

Comment: Check this out for verfication : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089829/7462031

Comment: I followed that implementation guide. OnTokenFresh works well but not OnMessageReceived

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.sademo.SademoEvent" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application android:label="SademoEvent.Android">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDxmjIsYXJ1OMWpqqheenbBoK5GKLWzAvg" />
      <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
      <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="yourAplicationName" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
      android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                 android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>



        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: You try my soluction?

Comment: I tried but he didn't compile me. He shows me an error and I don't know why he does it.   https://imgur.com/a/zJFuTIQ  . I've changed companyname to the name of my package but it's still the same.

Comment: you need to change "${applicationId}" for your project name.

Comment: I've already changed it but it's still the same. What is the ApplicationId exactly? The package? my package is not com.companyname.OtherName but com.otherName.OtherName. can that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, you need have the same package name, in application and Firebase.

Comment: They're the same. :S

Comment: Can you update your manifest on your question. I'll try to repair the code.

Comment: I've updated the manifest. I tried all the possibilities I could think of but it didn't work. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What a frustration I have. I will have some small line wrong but I can't find it. Would you give me your github user? I have prepared an example that should work with the same Package but still the same, thank you very much Rafa.