# Xamarin android push notification

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

I have done fcm registration and connection with hub and also i am able to register my device with tags but once the app is closed , i am not able to send push notifications to all older registered devices, i am getting error that registration id is no longer valid , my firebase notification OnMessage recieved doesn't call . So i want particular example where i can get help for this since many days i am working on this, i really want a good solution . Can any one help with working example or demo ??? I am doing this to send push notifications to android devices

Comment: If it happens while debugging, try release build. FCM isn't reliable in debug mode.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089829/7462031 and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin

Comment: What is the Error you are getting, Post the same Also Post the log it can help me find the issue,

Answer (score 0):

Check below link it will be helpful.

1. [Azure Push notification Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/push-notifications/azure)
2. [App Center Push notification Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-forms)
3. [Sample Code](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin)